# backing a cisco router, using NAPALM, using remote login using SSH

Tags: python, networking, cisco, napalm

[this image is the diagram for GNS3 of routers want to configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KKEc.png)Trying to Backup the configuration of a Cisco Router. but the connection is not opening.

```
    from napalm import *
    import napalm
    drivers = napalm.get_network_driver('ios')
    device_detail = {'hostname':'192.168.1.2','username':'wahid','password':'wahid'}
    router = drivers(**device_detail)
    router.open() 
#The problem is here <- Exception has occurred: ValueError
#Failed to enter enable mode. Please ensure you pass the 'secret' argument to #ConnectHandler.
    print('Connection is Opened with ->{}'.format(device_detail['hostname']))
    config = router.get_config()
    print('Configuratin on this {} router ->'.format(device_detail['hostname']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try as follows:

```
from napalm import get_network_driver
from getpass import getpass
 
 
hostname = input("IP address of router: ")
username = input(f"Username of {hostname}: ")
password = getpass(f"Password of {hostname}")
secret = getpass(f"Enable password of {hostname}: ")
 
driver = get_network_driver("ios")
device_detail = {
    "hostname": hostname,
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
    "optional_args": {
        "secret": secret
    }
}
 
with driver(**device_detail) as router:
    print(router.get_facts())
```